# Merging together two files based on common value but with different numbers of variables

Tags: r

I am trying to merge together two files, but i keep getting the following error:

```
Error: memory exhausted (limit reached?)
Error during wrapup: memory exhausted (limit reached?)
Error: no more error handlers available (recursive errors?); invoking 'abort' restart
```

I am using the following code:

```
FinalTweets <- merge(tweets2U, tweets2, by="author_id")
```

I alo realised that my files have a different number of values

For tweets2U

```
'data.frame':   325256 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ created_at: chr  "2015-02-18T02:56:55.000Z" "2016-05-23T02:14:36.000Z" "2013-04-22T02:52:16.000Z" "2015-03-06T02:40:55.000Z" ...
 $ author_id : chr  "3024607164" "734568179457007617" "1371107096" "3063885536" ...
```

and for tweets2

```
'data.frame':   338037 obs. of  4 variables:
 $ author_id                   : chr  "3024607164" "734568179457007617" "1371107096" "3063885536" ...
 $ created_at                  : chr  "2021-01-01T02:24:18.000Z" "2021-01-01T02:22:48.000Z" "2021-01-01T02:22:14.000Z" "2021-01-01T02:21:01.000Z" ...
 $ text                        : chr  "Super Game Talk Video Alpha!  The #1 Indie Video Game Review Show hosted by puppets! No"| __truncated__ "I was testing my game, and caught a fish that was a gold star (top 3 percentile in size) and I though \"Oh I be"| __truncated__ "Hey hey everyone just got home from work. Time to finish artwork before 12 am to show.super excited. I can fina"| __truncated__ "Congratulation to Pretumos who won our Dec 2020 $100 Zeegift! nMore members giveaways "| __truncated__ ...
 $ public_metrics.retweet_count: int  3 3 6 6 16 1 10 5 2 3 ...
```

Any recommendation on how to fix this ?
Maybe a different function could work ?
I also understand that the **left_join** function could be useful

Edit: I have updated my code, but i still run in the same issue

```
jointdataset <- merge(tweets2U, tweets2, by = 'author_id', all.x= TRUE)
View(jointdataset)

FinalTweets <- merge(tweets2U, tweets2, by=c("author_id","created_at"))
View(FinalTweets)

Error: no more error handlers available (recursive errors?); invoking 'abort' restart
```

I will try again in a few minutes, with no other program running on the computer
I have 16 Giga of Ram, which makes me confused as why there is not enough

Here is the data for the min reproducible example

```
> dput(head(tweets2U))
structure(list(created_at = c("2015-02-18T02:56:55.000Z", "2016-05-23T02:14:36.000Z", 
"2013-04-22T02:52:16.000Z", "2015-03-06T02:40:55.000Z", "2016-03-31T10:53:21.000Z", 
"2016-10-04T03:38:25.000Z"), author_id = c("3024607164", "734568179457007617", 
"1371107096", "3063885536", "715492170392846336", "783149246178553856"
)), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")

> dput(head(tweets2))
structure(list(author_id = c("3024607164", "734568179457007617", 
"1371107096", "3063885536", "1274386153035173891", "750763458719653888"
), created_at = c("2021-01-01T02:24:18.000Z", "2021-01-01T02:22:48.000Z", 
"2021-01-01T02:22:14.000Z", "2021-01-01T02:21:01.000Z", "2021-01-01T02:20:03.000Z", 
"2021-01-01T02:19:46.000Z"), text = c("Super Game Talk Video Alpha! ! The #1 Indie Video Game Review Show hosted by puppets! Now on Roku: Smiley Crew TV. #indiegame #gamedev #indiedev #indievideogames #marketing #indiegames #videogames #apple #ios #steam #roku ", 
"I was testing my game, and caught a fish that was a gold star (top 3 percentile in size) and I though \"Oh I better save the game\" Then I realized it's not done, and saving means nothing for me - but I really hope to evoke this feeling in others <U+0001F605>\n\n#gamedev #indiegame #pixelart ", 
"Hey hey everyone just got home from work. Time to finish artwork before 12 am to show.super excited. I can finally make more music with this midi keyboard for my game. #indiegame #rpg #artsoon #solodev #indiedev #madewithunity #indiegamedev ", 
"Congratulation to Pretumos who won our Dec 2020 $100 Zeegift!  \nMore members giveaways here: <U+0001F381>\nGuest Giveaways here:  \n@BlazedRTs @GamerGalsRT @SGH_RTs  #gaming #gamingcommunity #indiegame @GamingRTweeters ", 
"The lighting on my new level is really starting to come together<U+0001F60D>\n\nWhat do you think?\n\n#scifi #indiegame #art #gaming #game #indiegamedev #unity3d #games #twitchtv #shader #madewithunity #3d #3dart #twitch #stream #cyberpunk #artistsontwitter #indie #3dart ", 
"Super Game Talk Video Alpha!  The #1 Indie Video Game Review Show hosted by puppets! #indiegame #gamedev #indiedev #indievideogames #marketing #indiegames #videogames #apple #ios #steam "
), public_metrics.retweet_count = c(3L, 3L, 6L, 6L, 16L, 1L)), row.names = c(NA, 
6L), c
```

The expected output would lead to me having a single file with
Created_at, author_id and the text and the public_metrics.retweet_count that match this author_id

Comment: "my files have a different number of values": shouldn't be a problem.  `left_join` is not "limited to 500 values".  Are you sure you want to merge by just `author_id`? `created_at` appears to be another column the two dataframes have in common.   You maximise your chance of getting a useful answer if you provide a minimal reproducible example. [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) may help.

Comment: We are simply running out of memory. Either get more mem, or rethink the merge, maybe merge on author+date. Check how many authors overlap using `%in%`, check how many distinct author we have.

Comment: It does seem that the memory space is the issue 
any idea on how to fix that issue ?

Comment: I'd split tweet2U into smaller chunks, merge them in a loop and write it out to a file.

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear what kind of output you want. Do you want only rows that match both data.frame (`base::merge, dplyr::inner_join`)? or preserve all rows in x (`dplyr::left_join`)? or in y (`dplyr::right_join`). Furthermore, your error is not reproducible. As suggested by @Limey you should post a fully reproducible example or directly your data via `dput(tweet2U)` and `dput(tweets2)` or at least part of your data (`dput(head(your_data)`). However it is very strange that it could be a memory problem given the size of the data.

In my PC this code works well. An example with `dplyr::left_join`:

```
set.seed(4)
#simulate some data 
tweets2U <- data.frame(created_at=sample(seq(as.Date('2010/01/01'), as.Date('2020/01/01'), by="day"), 325256,,replace = T),
                       author_id=as.character(sample(1:325256,replace = T)))


tweets2 <- data.frame(created_at=sample(seq(as.Date('2010/01/01'), as.Date('2020/01/01'), by="day"), 338037 ,,replace = T),
                      author_id=as.character(sample(1:338037 ,replace = T)),
                       text=sample(letters,338037,replace = T),
                       public_metrics.retweet_count=sample(1:10,338037,replace = T))


FinalTweets <- dplyr::left_join(tweets2U, tweets2)

summary(FinalTweets)
```

the output of `summary`:

```
    created_at          author_id             text           public_metrics.retweet_count
 Min.   :2010-01-01   Length:325256      Length:325256      Min.   : 1.0                
 1st Qu.:2012-07-02   Class :character   Class :character   1st Qu.: 2.8                
 Median :2015-01-04   Mode  :character   Mode  :character   Median : 5.0                
 Mean   :2015-01-01                                         Mean   : 5.3                
 3rd Qu.:2017-07-02                                         3rd Qu.: 7.2                
 Max.   :2020-01-01                                         Max.   :10.0                
                                                            NA's   :325160
```

Comment: Thank you for your help !
I added the data for the minimum reproducible example in the main post 

The code you gave:
FinalTweets <- dplyr::left_join(tweets2U, tweets2)

Works, but data for both text and public_metrics.retweet_count are now NA

Comment: NA appears where there is no match between the two data.frame. You should also post an expected output